# SALESFORCE workflow to populate the field - doesn't work, help needed

Tags: automation, salesforce, workflow, crm

I have a problem with the workflow which I prepared for Communities users. The idea whole idea is to populate Address field according to the values which Communities users will enter. However, when I did the test it looks that the workflow doesn't work. I feel lost as everything looks fine for me. Here is the screenshot of my workflow:

[image: SCREEN OF THE WORKFLOW RULE]

and here is the action which I set up for this workflow:

[image]

At this point I was trying to refer to Description field just to be sure it works and it is not spoiled by any of Address field settings. However, it doesn't even populate the results in the Description field. Could anyone help me with that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the error in your field update. You are using description field in both places: as a field to Update and as a formula value. If you want, that description field are populated from adress field, you should chose adress field for formula value.